# OpenCV-Trouble using third party library

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

I have installed OpenCV ('3.0.0-dev') on my Ubuntu 14.04 and use it with python 2.7. It seams that the installation is correct. I can successfully run edge.py, and:
`import cv2` with no errors.

However when I try to use the Pyvision I get error:

```
 import cv
```

And I get the following error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in 
>       from cv2.cv import *
>   ImportError: No module named cv

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV 3 no longer has everything under `cv2.cv`, it's just `cv2`. To fix `cv.py`, use `sudo` to open `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py` in your favorite editor, and change it to:

```
from cv2 import *
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo. I still get a  new error" 'self.cascade = cv.Load( cascade_name )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Load''

Comment: @Sara I'd suggest opening an [issue](https://github.com/bolme/pyvision/issues) at the pyvision repo on Github. I'm having a bit of difficulty finding a good list of API changes between OpenCV 2 and 3, possibly because 3 hasn't officially been released yet, so I don't have any suggestions right off the bat. Good luck!